# How does observableArray work?

Tags: knockout.js

I have seen people using **observableArray** in many of the tutorials and using mapping to map data from server to models.

How does it actually work and what all are it's use cases ?

I understand that **observableArray** is after all an array of **observables** packed into one.

Thanks.

( I am a noob here, do ignore my ignorance. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to peep into the documentation

KnockoutJS is a JS **MV*** framework, with automatic UI refresh.

Taking from their [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

> If you want to detect and respond to changes of a collection of things, use an observableArray. This is useful in many scenarios where you’re displaying or editing multiple values and need repeated sections of UI to appear and disappear as items are added and removed.

So basically, what you do with observables is what you would do with observableArray , only when it's a collection of observables.

Also from there :

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects

Hope it helps.